# Visual Studio 2013: System-wide freeze when launching debugger

Tags: visual-studio-2013, freeze

I have a WPF solution in Visual Studio 2013 update 2 with over 100 projects, mostly C#.  I have a small C# exe as the start-up project which does some basic initialisation and displays a file open dialog which appears within a few seconds.

I have recently encountered an intermittent problem that occurs a few seconds after launching the debugger, usually before the file open dialog is displayed.  Visual Studio starts loading dependencies (visible in the status bar at the foot of the window), then suddenly goes unresponsive and fails to recover.

Crucially, it is impossible to launch new processes or close windows/terminate existing processes.  It is still possible to interact superficially with programs that were already running, i.e. menus in user interfaces are still clickable but have no effect.  Running any command in an open cmd prompt causes the window to stop responding; Ctrl+Alt+Del/Ctrl+Shift+Esc have no effect.  The only option is a hard reset.

I have tried deleting PDBs and performing a full clean/rebuild, to no avail.  There is also nothing of interest in the system or application event logs.

This issue started happening a few days ago and has become more regular, but remains intermittent.

Comment: That's an environmental problem, you'll need to get your machine healthy again.  Start by disabling/uninstalling the usual troublemakers, anti-malware and firewall first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the solution's SDF file, and the issue has not occurred since.